# calling asp.net stdef function from aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, function

is there any function for **stdev** in asp.net ? 
i tried using Math. function, but can not find it useful.

can you recommend me ?

tq before

Comment: Check out the answer I have submitted. Its very simple to determine standard deviation by just using 2 lines of VB.Net code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below function to find standerd deviation,

C#

```
private double CalculateStdDev(IEnumerable<double> values)
{   
  double ret = 0;
  if (values.Count() > 0) 
  {      
     //Compute the Average      
     double avg = values.Average();
     //Perform the Sum of (value-avg)_2_2      
     double sum = values.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));
     //Put it all together      
     ret = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (values.Count()-1));   
  }   
  return ret;
}
```

VB

```
Private Function CalculateStdDev(ByVal values As IEnumerable(Of Double)) As Double
    Dim ret As Double = 0
    If values.Count() > 0 Then
        Dim avg As Double = values.Average()
        Dim sum As Double = values.Sum(Function(d) Math.Pow(d - avg, 2))
        ret = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (values.Count() - 1))
    End If

    Return ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party library that is free and open-source. I have used `SmartStats` which you can download from [SmartStats download](https://smartstats.codeplex.com/releases).

1. Once you have downloaded this library which is just a dll file, you
   should put that file into the `bin` directory of your VB.Net Asp.Net
   project, or add a reference to it in your Vb.Net web app.
2. Then, you simply use code like below to determine standard deviation. `someNumbers` is an array of double values in code below.

   ```
   Dim disperse As SmartStats.dispersion = New SmartStats.dispersion()
   Dim stdDev As Double = disperse.StdDev(someNumbers)
   ```
3. You can use this library to determine many other statistical functions in case you need to do so in future. More details on what other statistical functions are available with this library can be seen at following url [Statistical functions with SmartStats library](https://smartstats.codeplex.com/)

A full working example of calculating standard deviation with this library, using code-behind of an aspx page is as given below.

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits Page

Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'create a collection of double numbers
    Dim someNumbers As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)()

    someNumbers.Add(2)
    someNumbers.Add(10)
    someNumbers.Add(6)
    someNumbers.Add(11)
    someNumbers.Add(14)
    someNumbers.Add(21)
    someNumbers.Add(1)
    someNumbers.Add(100)
    someNumbers.Add(65)

    'only below two lines are needed to determine standard deviation
    Dim disperse As SmartStats.dispersion = New SmartStats.dispersion()
    Dim stdDev As Double = disperse.StdDev(someNumbers.ToArray())

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thank you, let me try, how about **NORMSINV(probability),** ? is third-party library available for that function ? 

in smartstats doesn't has this function. thank you

Comment: I don't see that function in the documentation mentioned.  You could use https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ for that.

Comment: You can use following code to determine NORMSINV with math.net library that I mentioned in above comment :`Dim normalDistribution As MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal = New MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal(10.0, 6.34) ' ( mean, standard deviation)
        'specify properties for above normal distribution
        normalDistribution.InverseCumulativeDistribution(0.4) ' (probability)`